# Android read state of radiobuttons in custom dialog [update -> How to read from a custom dialog?]

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button

-- updated question --

I can't read any data from my custom dialog, at first i thought it was just the radiobuttons, so i thought lets continue the project so i give a default value for the testing purpose.

Even after i've tried to read from the EditText, i get nullpointerexceptions.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?? (below is the XML + code and in the comments below i've shown what i did with the EditText)

-- old question --

So, i've used multiple sources to combine the layout/check functions I am using now.

When i'm trying to see what radiobutton was selected i keep getting nullpointer errors, so i've searched in here and i have added some test to see if i could get results by seeing what was set via radiogroup (instead of individual buttons).

Let me show you what i've done/tried so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private RadioGroup rbs; //added for test
    private RadioButton rb1;
    private RadioButton rb2;
    private RadioButton rb3;
```

...

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.connectpopup);
        dialog.setTitle("Quick Connect");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.connect);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rbs = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.widget33); //added for test
                rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.nmdc);
                rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.adc);
                rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.adcs);
                //RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()
                Log.v("test", ""+rbs.getCheckedRadioButtonId()); //this doesn't give results either same nullpointer error
                if (rb1.isChecked() == true) { // these check for checked makes the app stop.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb1.getText(), 5).show();
                }
                if (rb2.isChecked() == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb2.getText(), 5).show();
                }
                if (rb3.isChecked() == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb3.getText(), 5).show();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
```

and the xml file i'm calling from:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/quickconnectpopup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please enter the address.\r\nSelect the protocol.\r\nEnter your nickname."
        >
    </TextView>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hubaddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some.address.com:411"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        >
    </EditText>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/widget33"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/nmdc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="protocol1"
            >
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/adc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="prototocol2"
            >
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/adcs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="protocol3"
            >
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nickname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nick"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        >
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect"
        >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>`

The error shows up when i'm trying to read (one or two of) this lines (same line was shown since i've added log.v lateron)

```
10:26:44.814    1124    ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10:26:44.845    1124    ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.NullPointerException
10:26:44.845    1124    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at nl.my.project.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:89)

Log.v("test", ""+rbs.getCheckedRadioButtonId()); //this doesn't give results either same nullpointer error
if (rb1.isChecked() == true) { // these check for checked makes the app stop.
```

So to state the exact question again, how could i retrieve the selected radiobutton.

in example show in Log.v("selected button:", variable); = 
`Verbose    Androidblabla    radio1`

Comment: Even just an idea might work, i'm now clueless. if you have not an immediate solution but think you have seen something i can start googling again, with the 3 words in my description i can't find any helpfull results on google anymore.

Comment: YaHubAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hubaddress);
                    Log.v("NMDC", YaHubAddress.getText().toString());

This gives the exact same error :S it seems that i can't read any data from the dialog at all :S

Comment: Answers are reserved for just that, answers. In the future, just edit your question to provide clarification. Stack Overflow is not a forum :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Johan... Might I suggest that you start by using the suggested architecture for creating and displaying a Dialog. So you would need to provide the method onCreateDialog(int id) and return the dialog in this method as in:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog;
        switch(id) {
        case MANAGE_PASSWORD:
            dialog= getInstancePasswordDialog(); //<== CREATE DIALOG HERE
            break;
        case DIALOG_ABOUT:
            // do the work to define the About Dialog
            dialog= getInstanceAlertDialog(); // called "the first time"
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
            break;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```

Where the password dialog is created as in:

```
private Dialog getInstancePasswordDialog() {
        final Dialog d= new Dialog(this);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.password_dialog);
        d.setTitle("Key Manager");
        final EditText editTextPasswordFirst= (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.EditTextPasswordFirst);
        final EditText editTextPasswordSecond= (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.EditTextPasswordSecond);
        // CANCEL BUTTON HANDLER
        final Button buttonCancel= (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.ButtonPasswordCancel);
        buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });
        // UPDATE BUTTON HANDLER
        final Button buttonUpdate= (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.ButtonPasswordUpdate);
        buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String entryFirst= editTextPasswordFirst.getText().toString();
                String entrySecond= editTextPasswordSecond.getText().toString();       
                if (entryFirst.equals(entrySecond)) { // do NOT use == with string values
                    if (entryFirst.length() != lengthPassword) { // invalid key length
                        editTextPasswordFirst.setText("Invalid Key Length of "+
                                new Integer(entryFirst.length()).toString());                       
                        editTextPasswordSecond.setText("");
                        editTextPasswordFirst.selectAll();
                        editTextPasswordFirst.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else {
                        editTextPassword.setText(entryFirst);
                        // *** Clear Key Fields ***
                        editTextPasswordFirst.setText("");                  
                        editTextPasswordSecond.setText("");
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                else { // entries do not match
                    editTextPasswordFirst.setText("Entries did not match!");                  
                    editTextPasswordSecond.setText("");
                    editTextPasswordFirst.selectAll();
                    editTextPasswordFirst.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        return d;
    }
```

Then show the dialog as in:

```
this.showDialog(MANAGE_PASSWORD);
```

Where:

```
private static final int MANAGE_PASSWORD= 0;
```

If you use the suggested architecture the Android OS will automagically handle orientation change so you do not want to launch a new dialog on each call to onCreate.